# Parent div won't display properly unless set to position:absolute

Tags: html, css, position

I working on a website that has 2 elements side by side inside of a parent element (I'm using `float:left` and `float:right` to control their positioning), but the parent element won't show up unless I set it to `position:absolute`. I can't do that because I am making a footer at the bottom of the website, and the parent element will be at a variable height.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxbure8w/3/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">div 2</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer">this is a footer</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background:blue;
    /* setting to position:absolute will make blue bg show up,
    but footer disappear */
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
#div1 {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding:20px;
}
#div2 {
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When elements are floated, they [are essentially removed from the normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow). Thus, if an element only contains floated elements (as in your case), the parent element will collapse upon itself and have a height of `0`.

A common approach to work around this is to [use a clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jmvkwaoa/)

```
#wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

or..

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jp9nuvqa/)

```
#wrapper {
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Alternatively, you could set an explicit height on the element, too.

---

I just noticed that you had a `.clear` element in your example (`<div class="clear"></div>`). For it to work, it would have had to be *inside* of the element with floated children:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8oqr56c8/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">div 2</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```